# Combining multiple maps that are stored on channel (Same key's values get summed.) in Go

Tags: string, dictionary, go, concurrency, channel

My objective is to create a program that counts every unique word's occurrence in a text file in a parallellised fashion, all occurrences have to be presented in a single map.

What I do here is dividing the textfile into string and then to an array. That array is then divided into two slices of equal length and fed concurrently to the mapper function.

```golang
   func WordCount(text string)  (map[string]int) {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    s := strings.Fields(newText)

    freq := make(map[string]int,len(s))
    channel := make(chan map[string]int,2)

    wg.Add(1)
    go mappers(s[0:(len(s)/2)], freq, channel,wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go mappers(s[(len(s)/2):], freq, channel,wg)
    wg.Wait()

    actualMap := <-channel


    return actualMap
```

```golang
func mappers(slice []string, occurrences map[string]int, ch chan map[string]int, wg *sync.WaitGroup)  {
    var l = sync.Mutex{}
    for _, word := range slice {
        l.Lock()
        occurrences[word]++
        l.Unlock()

    }
    ch <- occurrences
    wg.Done()
}
```

The bottom line is, is that I get a huge multiline error that starts with

> fatal error: concurrent map writes

When I run the code. Which I thought I guarded for through mutual exclusion

```golang
        l.Lock()
        occurrences[word]++
        l.Unlock()
```

What am I doing wrong here? And furthermore. How can I combine all the maps in a channel? And with combine I mean same key's values get summed in the new map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you use a separate lock in each goroutine. That doesn't do any help to serialize access to the map. The same lock has to be used in each goroutine.

And since you use the same map in each goroutine, you don't have to merge them, and you don't need a channel to deliver the result.

Even if you use the same mutex in each goroutine, since you use a single map, this probably won't help in performance, the goroutines will have to compete with each other for the map's lock.

You should create a separate map in each goroutine, use that to count locally, and then deliver the result map on the channel. This might give you a performance boost.

But then you don't need a lock, since each goroutine will have its own map which it can read/write without a mutex.

But then you'll do have to deliver the result on the channel, and then merge it.

And since goroutines deliver results on the channel, the waitgroup becomes unnecessary.

```
func WordCount(text string) map[string]int {
    s := strings.Fields(text)

    channel := make(chan map[string]int, 2)

    go mappers(s[0:(len(s)/2)], channel)
    go mappers(s[(len(s)/2):], channel)

    total := map[string]int{}
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        m := <-channel
        for k, v := range m {
            total[k] += v
        }
    }

    return total
}

func mappers(slice []string, ch chan map[string]int) {
    occurrences := map[string]int{}
    for _, word := range slice {
        occurrences[word]++

    }
    ch <- occurrences
}
```

Example testing it:

```
fmt.Println(WordCount("aa ab cd cd de ef a x cd aa"))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/c1zzPXkfOGn)):

```
map[a:1 aa:2 ab:1 cd:3 de:1 ef:1 x:1]
```

Also note that in theory this looks "good", but in practice you may still not achieve any performance boost, as the goroutines do too "little" work, and launching them and merging the results requires effort which may outweight the benefits.

Comment: Yeah, Im sorry but I left out the part in which I refine the string and split it on special characters and white spaces for simplicity's sake.

Comment: I tried creating a pointer type of a mutex and thus changing the signature of mapping so it takes in a mutex. But I still get that very same error.

Comment: @Synchrowave I revised my answer, proposed a new solution.

Comment: Exactly what I was just thinking after reading your initial answer, terrific! Thank you icza.

Comment: How come you omitted the wait group?

Comment: Because goroutines send result on the channel, and the "main" goroutines receives the results from the channel, so it will wait for them to complete (and send the result). So the waitgroup is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!  My code does actually work now thanks to you but I still have a couple of questions. I run Go in the Jetbrains IDEA GoLand and I still get that error I got initially, but after the error, the code performs the task I intended for it to perform. Do you perhaps know anything about that?

Comment: I posted the working, error-free code on the playground. If your IDE comolains about this specific code, it's the IDE's bug.